# TOAD exiting dialogue box?

Tags: toad

I started TOAD the first time and when I exited it a dialogue box appeared asking for a choice. I didn't really read it but just pressed `ok` anyway. After restarting TOAD and exiting it again the dialogue box didn't show up. What dialogue was it and how can I make it appear again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was most likely the Toad Improvement Program participation opt-in.

In Toad 13.1 and newer...

1. Launch Toad's Options window from the main View menu
2. Select the Online node on the left
3. Review the Toad Improvement Program groupbox on the right and set your preference accordingly

In Toad 13.0 and older...

1. Choose Product Improvement Program from Toad's Help menu

When opted in Toad sends anonymous statistics to track basic feature usage and exception logs.

Comment: I think that was the dialogue box, but I don't have a Toad Improvement Program groupbox in the node section.

Comment: What version of Toad are you using?

Comment: If you are on Toad 13.0 or older, look on the Help menu and choose Product Improvement Program. If you don't see it there, let me know which version of Toad you're using and I'll track it down.

Comment: Toad 12.10. I found what you described in the help menu.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "Confirm before closing Toad" option; it is located in Toad Options under the "General" node. I guess it is now unchecked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not this one, it was a bigger dialogue box.

Comment: How much bigger? Just kidding! Sorry, I wouldn't know what else could it be. As it is a *fresh* installation and you probably don't have much history nor connections, I'd suggest you to reinstall TOAD and see what happens. On the other hand, who knows what the Installer did to your computer and where TOAD put options you might have made, so - I'm not sure whether it would help at all as *uninstall* might keep those settings, somewhere, hidden. Perhaps, if you have some virtual machine to spare, try to install it there and repeat the "Close" action to see what was it about.